# Does BizTalk WCF-BasicHttp adapter actually verify the service certificate?

Tags: biztalk

I have a WCF-BasicHTTP send port configuredas follows:

- **Security tab** Security mode:Transport; 
  Transport client credential type: Certificate; 
  Client certificate: (thumbprint of our client cert); 
  Service certificate: (thumbprint of the service's public key cert).
- **General tab**, Endpoint Identity: everything is left blank.
- There is a send pipeline component that substitutes alternative endpoint addresses depending on the interaction type (all endpoints share the same base URL).

Recently, our trading partner has renewed their server certificate, and failed to notify us in advance. The send port continues working (good). **However**, the behaviour leads me to believe that even though BizTalk forced me to specify **some** service certificate thumbprint, the adapter then does not actually verify the service certificate thumbprint against what's set in the binding. I can't figure out if this is a bug or by design?

Comment: Does it work with nothing in the Service certificate option?  It should....

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, it should, -- but won't let you save the configuration as long as security = transport. My question is -- what's the point of forcing the thumbprint to be input if the expected behaviour is not to verify that thrumbprint unless the service identity fields on the other tab are populated?...